# Как прервать выполнение метода?

Tags: java

Какие способы существуют для того чтобы прервать выполнения метода?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если метод ничего не возвращает (`void`), то можно выполнить оператор `return`, который завершит работу метода (или, проще, выйдет из него). Пример использования

```
public void foo(int n) {
if(n < 0) return;
else bar(n);
}
```

В этом случае перед вызовом метода `bar` идет проверка на отрицательное число `n`.

Как по мне оператор `return` в `void` методах в 80% случае можно заменить на какую-то логику, например метод выше можно переписать вот так

```
public void foo(int n) {
if(n >= 0) bar(n);
}
```

Если метод что-то возвращает, то оператор `return` используется всегда (так как он возвращает) а иногда и более одного раза (в методах с разветвляющейся логикой)

```
public String foo(int n) {
if(n == 1) return "ONE";
if(n == 2) return "TWO";
return "WTF!?";
}
```

@Regent в комментариях меня поправил. Раз уж оператор `return` вернет значение и закончит выполнение метода, то лесенка `if/else` не нужна

Comment: `s/else //g` ни к чему они тут, все)

Comment: @vp_arth однако конструкция `if (x) { return foo; } else { return bar; }` лучше воспринимается: "если что-то выполняется, то верни первое, иначе верни второе". В общем, штука субъективная: указывать необязательный `else` или нет.

Comment: @Regent, вы правы. Зачем здесь `else` если  есть `return`

Answer (score 3):

1. С помощью оператора `return`. `return;` для `void`-методов и `return value;` для других методов.
2. Пробросить исключение: `throw new Exception();`. В этом случае у метода должно быть указано `throws Exception`. На практике пробрасывается конкретное исключение (например, `IndexOutOfBoundsException`), зачастую с текстом ошибки.

Далее идут нестандартные способы, которые на практике используются крайне редко, однако они всё же останавливают выполнение метода:

3. `System.exit(status);`, он же `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(status);`. Останавливает работу программы.
4. Deprecated-метод `stop` у `Thread`: `Thread.currentThread().stop();`. Про то, почему он deprecated, прочитать можно [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).