# Activity продолжает работу после закрытия

Tags: java, android

```
.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.go_to) + " " + getString(R.string.level_selector), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();
                    System.out.println("HELLO");
                    }
                })
```

Как может быть такое, что после `finish()` в **LogCat** выводится *HELLO*?

Возможно ли **полностью закрыть** activity, чтобы например не исполнялась команда `System.out.println("HELLO")`?

Comment: в ОС Android решает операционная система какой процесс завершить (вы можете просто ей сказать, что процесс больше не нужен, что и делает метод finish()), Ваша Activity для операционной системы - всего лишь процесс. Так делают все *nix системы )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `finish()` закрывает активити, но не прерывает выполнение кода. Чтобы прервать дальнейшее выполнение кода текущего метода используйте команду `return;`

Answer (score 0):

Закрытие активити происходит асинхронно. Вам нужно это учитывать. Не пытайтесь найти способ это обойти - это будет костыль и у вас не будет гарантии того, что он будет работать всегда и везде.

Answer (score 0):

Код прерывается командой return, а не finish.
Вот здесь можно подробнее посмотреть :

[Как прервать выполнение метода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634630/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)